# Find the minute difference between 2 date time

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get the difference between 2 date time in minutes(Time difference in minutes). And the last difference will be calculated based on 6 PM of every date.

Sample data: need result of last column

```
User_Name   Date            Time difference in minutes
User 1  1/1/06 12:00 PM     30
user 2  1/1/06 12:30 PM     315
user 3  1/1/06 5:45 PM      15
```

Here the date will be always in same date and the last user date difference calculated based on default value 6PM. Assuming the dates of any user will not cross 6PM time.

Please suggest how to write the query for the same.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `lead` window function.

I assume your table is called `mytable` and the date column is `mydate` (it is a bad idea to call a column `Date` as it is a reserved word).

```
select   user_name,
         round((lead(mydate, 1, trunc(mydate)+18/24) 
             over (partition by trunc(mydate) order by mydate) 
         - mydate) *24*60) as difference 
from     mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.. if its not correct let me know

```
SELECT User_name,created_date,
trunc(to_number((cast(nvl(lead (created_date,1) OVER (ORDER BY created_date),TRUNC(SYSDATE) + (19/24)) as date) - cast(created_date as date)))*24*60) as difference
FROM users;
```